# Unable to change anything in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, 12.10

I recently installed Gnome 3 and now I have found out that it has messed up with nautilus. The menu bar and the right click menu are completely devoid of options. Also, the icons look different. How to get back the default nautilus? I'm using Unity (used Gnome 3 for only a day). I have attached a screenshot.

Please help! :)

[image: Screenshot of my home folder in Nautilus]

Comment: How did you install gnome3 and how did you uninstall it? The nautilus version in Ubuntu is an older on (in order to keep all the options that users like) whereas Gnome3 uses a newer nautilus (which has removed lots of options...).

Comment: I haven't uninstalled Gnome 3 yet. I installed Gnome 3 from a terminal. I used these commands

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3` 
`sudo apt-get update` 
`sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`

Comment: Is it necessary to uninstall Gnome 3 to get the default Nautilus back??

Comment: One more question to be sure: when you open Nautilus, could you check if "Help" -> "About" shows the version number 3.4.2 (then it would be the normal ubuntu version)?

Comment: It says 3.6.1
This is weird. A newer version should add features, but here it is dumbed down

So what do I do now?

Comment: No: the reason why Ubuntu chose 3.4.2 is that gnome3 removed so many features from the newer version. I will add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
2. sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
3. sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
4. killall nautilus (or restart or log out and back in)

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-install-nautilus-36-or-patched.html

Comment: I guess I'll do this. Don't find myself using Gnome anyway.

Comment: Fantastic! This worked

Answer (score 1):

By adding the gnome3 ppa, you added newer version of many programs to the repository.

You "updated" nautilus to a version which has many features removed (see e.g. here: [OMG](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/is-the-new-nautilus-a-step-in-the-direction-poll) )

You can basically do two things:

1. Remove the ppa, update the package list, remove nautilus, then reinstall it: basically, follow the answer on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106044/how-do-i-downgrade-gracefully-from-gnome3)
2. Try to only revert nautilus (this might fail, depending on the dependencies...). See [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/52029/how-to-force-downgrade-of-packages-on-ubuntu-karmic).